# Reputation that exceeds the daily reputation cap should be reserved for bounties

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit

A recent answer of mine benefited from being the accepted answer of a hot network question. This caused me to hit my reputation cap, and I was lamenting the "loss" of all of those points. Taking for granted that the reputation cap is a good thing, I think that it would be nice if there were *some* benefit to all those subsequent upvotes.

I propose that any reputation that exceeds the cap should go into a separate bucket, one that can only be used for bounties. Having a separate count of points which is only possible to give away would encourage me to be a bit more liberal with my bounties, which in turn is likely to encourage the receivers of said bounties to keep on providing good content.

---

Anecdotally, I had this idea because I have Reddit coins (for some reason). When I saw my Q&A posted on Reddit, I gave those posts Reddit Gold, merely because I was in a good mood from the bounty of upvotes and felt like sharing the happiness.

In retrospect, I wondered why I didn't do the same here on Stack Overflow, and I think that the main reason was because that was all I could use those coins for.

Comment: Not a bad idea, IMHO, although I assume that it could technically be a bit fiddly to maintain another "score" for each user... and ... while I agree that it might encourage *some* people to be more gracious with bounties, 1. I think that the rep-cap is reached rarely enough to really benefit a substantial number of people and 2. for you case: 174k ... you could donate 80 percent of your rep without losing a privilege ... don't be such a scrooge ;-)

Comment: eh, I'd rather not encourage more bounties to be used.

Comment: @Marco13 I do realize that I'm in no shortage of reputation, and debated bringing that up directly in the question. :-) However, having a "bank" of points that can *only* be used for bounties would still trigger a different mental pathway (at least for me!).

Comment: @KevinB That seems like a point that could be expanded on as an answer — I'm certainly operating from the POV that more bounties would be a good thing!

Comment: I personally find bounties to be good for nothing other than increasing drive-by upvotes on otherwise questionable quality posts.

Comment: Personally I'd rather have a second rep threshold not dependent of the time we get the upvotes. A question or answer should not bring more than 2000 points.

Comment: If I search for my best answers, I won't found them, they're buried behind trivial ones which gave me a lot of points due to the luck of timing, or of being among the first one to look at a specific technology. It's not right that some old and simple answers bring me points every weeks.

Comment: If bounties were free to give... There would be rings. Even informal ones, just friends mutually "liking" their posts...

Comment: @DenysSéguret, Bounty rings already happen. People in the same tag giving 500-rep bounties to each other in turn. If it's noticed, but the posts are of high quality and the bounty-givers/takers are otherwise reputable (not necessarily equals high reputation), then the community usually turns a blind eye. Net the ring benefits from increased visibility, which usually means upvotes.

Answer (score 20):

## I disagree with this proposal

A bounty is someone literally giving up reputation to benefit another person.  Upvotes on answers are free and do not involve any commitment of any passer-by.

The commitment of someone giving up reputation is rewarded, which is a large reason why the reputation cap is ignored when a bounty is awarded.

Comment: *A bounty is someone literally giving up reputation to benefit another person* — The daily reputation cap is effectively another way of giving up reputation, albeit forced. This proposal would allow me to direct where it goes, instead of it being lost. *Upvotes on answers are free and do not involve any commitment* — but the reputation transferred as a bounty comes from upvotes on answers (and questions, and other bounties, etc.); I'm not sure why "commitment" matters here.

Comment: @Shepmaster - someone's *losing* reputation to *award* a bounty.  No one's losing anything to upvote a question.  Rep cap also keeps people who are "popular" from being bestowed with real privileges and powers despite not having a ton of experience on the site *too* quickly.  Yes, it's possible for someone to get awarded four 500-rep bounties to get 2K rep in a day.  It's nowhere near as likely as someone just getting upvoted a bunch because they wrote a book.

Comment: *someone's losing reputation to award a bounty* — does that mean you feel that the zero-sum nature of bounties is important? However, I'm still not completely following. I am **already** "losing" reputation that I've "earned" since I hit the reputation cap, so why not transfer that enforced loss into bounties that I must give?

Comment: Because that rep is "free". you're literally obligated to give it away. that's backwards, you should instead decide that a post is worthy of spending rep, rather than having a pool sitting there that is useless if you don't spend it. It promotes using bounties in cases where you generally wouldn't.

Comment: @Shepmaster:  The system isn't awarding you reputation for missed upvotes, so you're not *losing* anything.  You're just not *gaining* anything for it.

Comment: @Makoto that feels like some very subtle splitting of hairs, especially considering that this one answer prevents the reputation gains from all my other answers, which feels much more of a loss. Regardless, with my proposal I'm still not *gaining* anything; I'm giving that reputation (via bounty) to other people that have asked good questions and provided good answers.

Comment: @Shepmaster:  Actually...you're *gaining* reputation which you would otherwise have to forfeit when awarding a bounty, so yes, you'd be gaining something here.

Comment: If this was implemented retroactively, i would probably have 20k rep to award in bounties at this point. I have a hard time finding questions worth answering, much less questions worth bountying.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this opens up an unnecessary avenue for abuse.

Think about the following situation:

- A user hits the rep cap and sees they can award a bounty with the additional rep
- Said user creates a sock puppet and awards the bounty to their new account
- The user then turns around and awards a new bounty back to their main account. They might lose a little rep in the process, but they've got a large portion of their above-rep-cap reputation.

Now, this isn't a very likely situation. Not many posts hit the rep cap. It also should be relatively easy to check for (just routinely check reciprocating bounties for abuse). But it's adding yet another way users abuse the system that the mods would have to be aware of and look out for, and for negligible benefit (being able to award a few more imaginary internet points to someone). Therefore I say no to the proposal.

Comment: Bounty awards don't count towards the rep cap, so this would be uni-directional anyway.

Comment: @Makoto I know they don't count towards the rep cap, that's the whole reason for the example. If they also counted towards the rep cap, the third step wouldn't be able to award the rep back to the user over the top of their rep cap. I'm talking about a user getting some couple hundred points in this bounty-only rep bucket, and using two bounties to award it back to their main account, circumventing the rep cap.

Comment: Isn't that just the run-of-the-mill voting fraud we see these days anyway?  This would enable it to happen easier, but I'm not seeing this as a different scenario.

Comment: @Makoto The difference here is that if I award a bounty to a sock puppet now and then back to myself, I get no net benefit because I'd only be getting my own rep back. But if I did the same with this bounty-only rep fund the question is requesting, I'd be able to, after a pair of bounties, award that rep to myself that currently is unaccessible. Sure, it would be perpetrated by the same voting fraud people as always, but it would be something new that mods would have to look out for. That's a low risk of course, but evaluating low risk against negligible benefit, the risk wins out.

Comment: This is not that unlikely actually. As moderators we deal with sockpuppets all the time and the damage they do if undetected for a while is at least fairly limited. With the rep cap turned into bounties however....

Comment: Fun story: the largest sock network I ever detected and cleaned up consisted of 165 socks. The network had grown so large because their master had been *ever so careful* at trying to avoid detection. By the time I cleaned everything up they had been working on the sock network for 3 months. They managed to gain 4000 points from their activities, including a few bounties (all gone when we were done, and the user suspended).  4K is a pittance, put the same work into answering and you can make 30k legitimately in the same time.

Comment: Now, if hitting the rep cap got turned into bounties however.... the point is that running sock network is hard work and not really worth it, because not getting caught means the gains are very very low. With rep caps to bounties that could  radically change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is the implication that a large sock puppet ring would all upvote each other, exceeding each member's rep cap, then use the "bonus bounties" to funnel all the rep to one user?

Comment: @Shepmaster that’s exactly what that sock ring did. They did so to gain enough rep to vote for the master account content and to keep from being question banned. But if they voted just a little more then they hit free bounty land!