# Accuracy of "Voting Fraud" detection

Tags: support, upvotes, voting-fraud

I recently flagged a suspicious voting pattern and I was right since my flag was helpful and the user got deleted. I have also noticed a bunch of "User Removed" on my profile (7 to be precise) and I am pretty sure it was related to the cleanup of the voting ring since the *bad* user was active in [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and I have interacted with them on many posts.

From this, I understood that there were 7 accounts voting for that user and other users around (including me). My question here:

Why didn't the system catch such behavior before my flag? 7 accounts seems a lot to me and it should be *easy* to identify the voting ring.

The other question is how can we make sure that I am not the *bad* guy in this story??! All the accounts voted for me too so it's easy for anyone to create them to vote for me then flag me like I did for that user!

It would be difficult to know that I am getting *false* upvotes since I am active and getting upvotes each day.

Comment: I would assume that automatic actions are quite rare on purpose to avoid deleting false-positives. And avoiding the rather simple mechanic seems to be easy, just also vote for other users, like they voted for you as well.

Comment: Fun fact, Martijn once cleaned up a [165-sock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387991/reputation-that-exceeds-the-daily-reputation-cap-should-be-reserved-for-bounties/387997#comment717861_387997) ring. It took 3 months to deal with it fully.

Comment: @DavyM it didn’t take me 3 months. It took me a day or two. The network of puppets was 3 months old when I took it down.

Comment: Voting fraud is more complex and nuanced then you think it is. It's not like you can just flick a script and catch all of them or even most of them. I know this because I tried at some point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not going to divulge what the system can and can't catch. I hope you understand why we wouldn't want to do that.

Yes, there were more accounts involved here, and there were more than 7. You just happened to have answered a few posts from this network. Sorry you lost some reputation!

Comment: I don't really care about the reputation, it's not a problem. It's even a good thing as I don't want those *side effect* upvotes (I only want real ones). I was simply curious about the *behind the scene* but It seems the door is closed for me :)