# Dozens of users removed resulted in -366 reputation

Tags: support, reputation-history, sock-puppets

I don't usually make a fuss about a small reputation shock due to "User removed". Over the last couple of days, though, two aspects of the reputation shock are a bit worrying:

1. It appears from the detail there are *dozens* of users being removed, see screenshot below.
2. In the very small number of popular tags where I contribute, no other regular users seem to have suffered a single -10 "User removed".

So my question to moderators: was there a sock puppet ring revolving around me that I never knew about?

[image]

Comment: I once got around [8 Users removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392900/8620333) but you beat me here ;) .. by the way, moderator won't give you a *clear* reply since this is supposed to be a secret but this is for sure a disassembled Voting Ring   .. by the way I got one today (probably from the same Voting Ring)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Understood... but this is literally 30+ users. Which seems remarkable to me. Seems like a ring which revolves only around me!

Comment: Forgive me for being a little unsure but is this really 30 users or just 30 *votes* being removed....If a user or several users have voted on many different questions/answers, wouldn't their deletion look exactly the same as 30 users each voting once?

Comment: @Paulie_D has a point. If one user has upvoted two posts, then removing the user will remove 2 * 10 rep. I've actually been thinking about this recently - people with very high reputation scores usually have a lot of answers that are very prominent on old questions. So, they are very likely to be seen a lot. I got thinking about this because I suddenly became worried - I was browsing few old and VERY popular questions and upvoted good answers on them. But the answers were from the same people, so I was worried if it would count as targeted voting, yet those users simply provide good content.

Comment: So, seeing you have a lot of rep and a lot of highly upvoted answers, then it's entirely possible that even a single person found them helpful and upvoted them...then was deleted. Or it might have been, say 2-5 people or something.

Comment: Well some of your question may look pretty appealing in order to look human. Perhaps you are a top user on a tag where the voting ring was really active and they just voted for few of the top questions in order to evade detection. Or a singular case of "Upvote cute things, Hoo a turtle!"

Comment: I'm really sorry, jpp. You have been the one victim most affected by this ring. It's a real shame we didn't catch this particular scheme sooner.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks very much - that's all the confirmation I needed.

Comment: @DragandDrop I love jpp's turtles. I wish they used more unicorns. I need to post a proposal on meta for a requirement for MRUs on unappealing code questions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I can confirm that was a very large network of sockpuppet accounts (100+).

These accounts voted across a number of users to attempt to evade detection for a number of years, of which several have been recently uncovered by observant users who flagged moderators, who in turn found all the remaining accounts with the same M.O. (*we cannot reveal more info*)

While I am unsure why you ended up with that many targeted votes from these socks, I hope you can find peace now knowing that your reputation is no longer tainted by these rogue accounts.

Comment: you said *for a number of years*?? how many years?

Comment: years = more than one

Comment: Fascinating. Forgive my naïveté but to what end? Or were they also upvoting each other, and the OP was just cover? Not trying to pry, just wondering how to spot this sort of pattern.

Comment: "Evil mods take away the socks of people" for *shame*! Now there are people walking barefoot because of you.

Comment: @matt that's usually the M.O. of a voting ring - boost the votes of several accounts. Space this between many fake accounts to evade detection. Also, try to vote for other content in order to not seem like the users only vote for particular content.

Comment: @matt Yep, the goal with effective bots on any network is to establish a baseline of credibility. This throws off detection algorithms because they look like normal (read: random, distributed) patterns of activity. If you create 10 accounts in one day that all upvote an 11th account at the same time, it's pretty obvious. But if you create 10 accounts over weeks or months who upvote random accounts (even better if they upvote known-good content like this case) and then at different times give the occasional upvote to that 11th user, it pretty much *requires* human inspection to uncover.

Comment: Clearly I need to think of easier ways to boost my rep other than crushing my rivals beneath the weight of my withering insightful logic.

Comment: A *lot* of [similar work has been done](https://www.wired.com/story/russia-ira-propaganda-senate-report/) re: Russian-backed bot accounts across different networks on the web by those such as Renee DiResta and others.

Comment: @SamuelLiew 100+ sounds pretty significant. Is this the largest ring ever uncovered?

Comment: @TylerH no, just shy of the record actually

Comment: @SamuelLiew, This one was very interesting. It seems a number of accounts upvoted a *single answer* of mine which got me a "Guru" (40+ score) badge and now has < 10 score. The reversal seems entirely right to me, it is hardly my best answer.

Comment: @matt crush other answerers. See them driven before you. Hear the lamentations in the comments.

Comment: @VLAZ what about *hot water, good dentishtry and shoft lavatory paper*, though?

Comment: I have a worrying suspicion that such activity is responsible for a large proportion of the otherwise-almost-inexplicable upvoting of megadupe/mediocre/bad questions:(

Comment: @MartinJames ah, that would be best in life.

Comment: @matt "to what end?" The end of arms. Or legs. Or both. They are SOCKPUPPETS. Whatever it takes to get REP REP REPREPREPREPREPREPREP.

Comment: so many accounts probably made many posts, is it possibly to guess their motivation based on these? Resume boosting, circumventing asking limits, promoting a product/site etc

Comment: Oh, the irony — I just lost 70 points on presumably similar grounds, so clearly you guys are on a roll! :)